# Pinia store loses reactivity after updating value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Okay I see this example works in the sandbox which means it has some thing to do with my setup.

If you could have a look at my repository that would be much appreciated:

[GithubRepo](https://github.com/frankastin2023/card_designer/tree/main/card-personaliser/src)

The files in question are:
`stores/cardStore.js` - where the store is defined
`composables/loadData.js` - where the store array is first updated
`composables/discardSavedCard.js` - this is where the array is updated and does not effect the UI
`components/imageLayers/ImageLayers.js` Where the UI doesn't update

I have a Pinia store which is an object with a array of objects.

When I change properties within the objects the parts of the UI using the properties update as expected.

When I change the nested array to a new array with new objects in it, the state does change but the parts of the UI do not update and act as if the array has not changed.

**Update Store Script**

```js
import { useExampleStore } from "@/stores/exampleStore";

const updateStore () => {
    const exampleStore = useExampleStore();

    exampleStore.array = [{prop:'newprop'}];
};
```

**Example UI**

```html
<template>
    <div> {{exampleStore.array[0].prop}} </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useExampleStore } from "@/stores/exampleStore";
const exampleStore = useExampleStore();
</script>
```

**@\stores\exampleStore.js**

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useExampleStore = defineStore("exampleStore", {
  state: () => ({}),
});
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Sandbox attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-andras-rhrjlf?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Yes it seems to work in the sandbox which means it something specific to my code, added repo link.

Comment: [This might be your problem](https://i.imgur.com/tKawYOz.png), caught with eslint (great tool).  As it says, destructuring props causes them to lose reactivity, by doing this any update to your props will not update your UI.  Remove the destructuring. Just the line of code `defineProps(['view', 'viewIndex', 'card'])` will work.  You only need to assign props when using them in `<script>`. Never by destructuring though, assign to a single variable usually called `props`.  In this component though since you're only using props in the template you don't need to even do that much.

Comment: @yoduh Thanks for looking at the code, I've just made a change so that `/components/imageLayers/imageLayers.js`  directly accesses the store rather than using `defineProps` and I still get the same behaviour.   It is odd because everything works fine before I update the Array.